# How can I open more than one yahoo e-mail at the same time on IE8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, email

How can I open more than one yahoo e-mail at the same time on IE8?

Comment: Of course, you could run different browser instances to achieve this (IE, Chrome, Firefox) -- but, that will not answer your question.

Comment: Look Here :http://salesittech.blogspot.com/2009/07/open-multiple-gmail-accounts-with-ie8.html

Comment: Have you tried the private browsing?

Answer (score 1):

**Open multiple web accounts of same website**

To use this feature, goto file > new session and open multiple sessions of same web service in Internet Explorer 8.

Each session will have own cookies allowing you to access multiple accounts at the same time.

> To open new session manually, goto start > Run and then type `iexplore.exe -nomerge` and click on OK

[(source)](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/open-multiple-web-accounts-of-same-website-in-ie8/)

Answer (score 0):

You could launch a "InPrivate" browsing session in a new window and use one copy of yahoo in the private session. Look in the tools menu for "InPrivate Browsing". In general you need to have the InPrivate browsing session in a new window, but IE8 should open this for you.

Comment: This is otherwise known as porn mode.